# How to know which Python gets affected by pip command?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

If I have several Python installations and I want to know which one gets executed by command `python`, I can do

```
python -c "import sys; print(sys.prefix)"
```

How can I (or a program) determine, which Python installation is related to `pip` (or `pip3` or `pip3.5`) command? Lets pretend I have several installations of Python 3.5 in different locations.

Comment: `import  pip;print(pip.main(["--version"]))`

Comment: You can even control what version of pip you are calling by using `python -m pip` instead of using the `pip` script

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pip --version` tells you not only which Pip version you are running, but also informs you about the associated Python installation.

From the commandline, I get:

```
>pip --version
pip 6.0.8 from H:\Python34\lib\site-packages (python 3.4)
```

Comment: @PadraicCunningham my pip likes to remind me of that.. a lot. :)

Comment: `pip --version | awk '{ print $4}'` will just pull the path

Comment: Thanks! I needed to know whether a `pip`command is related to a `python` command. Your answer gave me idea that I can compare the output from `pip --version` and `python -c "import pip; pip.main(['--version'])"`